# Angular Dynamic input Width

Tags: angular

All,

I have been trying to get my input (type=text) to dynamically resize the input box. I have read multiple posts in SO, but was trying to come up with the simplest solution.

I have my simple component up and running at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-textbox-width

Firstly, I do not understand why the width property is not taking effect in the [style.width]. What am I missing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot to put `px` at the end

change `[style.width]='width'` to `[style.width.px]='width'` :D